# How to sort ArrayList with two properties?

Tags: java, android, sorting, arraylist

I have an Arraylist and I want to sort ArrayList by two properties 
1.By Name(Alphabetical Order)
2.By a custom Key

More Explanation -:

```
ArrayList<User> list = new ArrayList();

Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<User>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(User user, User t1) {
        1.By User.getName() (Alphabetically)
        2.By User.getRelationshipState() (Custom property)


});
```

`

Comment: what is `By a custom Key` ?

Comment: What do you mean by "custom Key"? Do you want to change the key to sort for everytime you sort? Or is this just some field of the `User` class?

Comment: Custom key like user.getRelationshipState
which is 
   public  final static int REQNOTSENT =0;
    public final static int REQUESTSENT =1;
    public final static int FRIENDS=2;
    public final static int REQUESTRCVED =3;


I want to sort like 
     Friends
    REQUESTSENT
    REQUESTRCVED
    REQNOTSENT

Answer (score 1):

Your object need to implement the Comparable interface.

[See javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html)

Comment: Kindly Can you explain this litter bit pls?

Comment: This doesn't even sounds like a potential comment.

Comment: Sorry, but this won't take him further than what he already tried with the Comparator.